# Value "_new" in target= attribute not supported in HTML5?

Tags: html

I decided to stop using `_blank` and start using `_new` to avoid slapping users with new windows as much as possible and instead have one single 'new window' and have all the links that open in a new window open in that window that's already opened, that's what `_new` is for.

I've been looking around the web and Stackoverflow but no one really addresses the value `_new` in the attribute *target=* in HTML5.

There's this forum but there's no comment about the `_new` value: [Html Target Attribute not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399621/html-target-attribute-not-supported).

In W3Schools there's no mention of the `_new` value in the table they have there: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_a.asp

So my question is: Does anyone know if using `target="_new"` is valid/correct in HTML5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `_new` never really existed.

The behavior you give to `_new` actually works with any other valid name:
If a window with the chosen name do exists, it is used, instead if it doesn't exists, is created.

**"name" clarification**:

If you open a new tab/window with an arbitrary target, like  `target='mywindow'`, you have "named" that new window (as "mywindow" in this case).

Then, following again a link with the same target, the browser re-uses the same window if still exists, otherwise opens a new one.

Comment: What do you mean by "window with the chosen name do exists"? Can you elaborate please? Thanks.

Comment: UVL, thanks for the explanation. But, can you use an arbitrary value like  "mywindow" then? Aren't we supposed to use only _blank, _top, _self and _parent? In reading W3C's spec seems this is possible, although it's kind of hard to really understand W3C's language: "A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)". Did I understand this right?

Comment: Yes, _blank, _self, _parent, and _top are special values, each with a different behaviour, while any other valid name is used as I wrote above. The same works with the now obsolete "framesets", where you gave a different name to each frame, then using target to select where links are opened.

Comment: Ah! Well, I did not know that you could use arbitrary values for the `target=` attribute. Although George's solution was extremely informative, this is the exact solution to my question above. Thanks for your time UVL.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [working draft of the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword), the contents of the `target` attribute must be a "valid browsing context name" (which does not start with an underscore ('_') or one of '_blank, _self, _parent, or _top.'

> A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)
>
> A valid browsing context name or keyword is any string that is either a valid browsing context name or that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of: _blank, _self, _parent, or _top.

So, it appears that `_new` is not supported.

Comment: You're right George. So, what can be used to accomplish the same results of `_new`?

Comment: IMHO, the user should be allowed to decide whether to open a link in a new window or the current one. In many browsers, this is accomplished by holding or not holding the Control key while clicking a link.

Comment: Yes, well, but sometimes the content can't be displayed in the same window since for content architecture reasons the link takes the user to another property/website, so that's why we use a 'new window' icon together with the `title` attribute to let the user know that link will open in a new window. Ok, no probl, I'll see which attribute of the above works. Thanks again.

Comment: You know what, none of them work but I decided to stay with `_new` even if HTML5 doesn't support it, it doesn't make sense to me that I have to open a new window/tab for every single new window link. Talk about 'respect for the user'.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you are currently doing, do a global search/replace and change "_new" to a name for the target "frame". See the [HTML5 anchor tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_a_target.asp).

Comment: Yep, that's the same link a put above in my comment. Thanks though.